# The inheritance argument of zope.interface (providedby vs isinstance)

Tags: python, object-oriented, interfaces

What limitations does inheritance of an interface through an abstract base class present that are addressed by zope.interface?

In the [following talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/347/pycon-2010--interfaces--adapters-and-factories---) given in 2010 by Jeff Rush about interfaces, at 11:50 Jeff argues that with providedby you are free of the inheritance hierarchy.  Why is this important?

If I wanted to use an interface and inherit behavior from another base class, Python grants me the opportunity to do so with multiple inheritance.  I understand that multiple inheritance should be avoided, and a compositional design to be considered as an alternative, but in this case I'm not inheriting behavior from the abc but rather just an interface, so I'm not really multiple inheriting in the behavioral sense.

I don't understand the inheritance argument..

Thanks in advance for sharing your insight.

**EDIT, updated video link:** [via Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160121001325/http://05d2db1380b6504cc981-8cbed8cf7e3a131cd8f1c3e383d10041.r93.cf2.rackcdn.com/pycon-us-2010/347_interfaces-adapters-and-factories-181.ogv).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "If I wanted to use an interface and inherit behavior from another base class, Python grants me the opportunity to do so with multiple inheritance."? Are you referring to where you do inheritance from multiple classes that aren't child classes of each other? (Eg. Like class Car and class Animal, from which the 2 classes will have no direct relation and justify no inheritance between them, both being used for "class AnimalinCar", which inherits from them both).

Comment: I implement an interface using as an abstract base class, I subclass the abc.  If I want to implement this interface and inherit from another class, I can.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521189/purpose-of-zope-interfaces

Comment: In an attempt to understand the differences (pros and cons) myself I've created https://bitbucket.org/prologic/oop_zca_circuits -- I haven't yet formulated any opinions or objective reasonining so right now it's just an implemtnation comparision of three different approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video does not appear to be available as of December 2016, but I agree with you that interface inheritance is not as problematic as implementation inheritance.  See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/260354 for example.

However, one sense in which the `zope.interface` "provider" relationship frees us from the inheritance hierarchy is that it allows objects to provide an interface even if their class does not. https://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/README.html#declaring-provided-interfaces shows examples of objects directly providing an interface although their respective classes do not.

For example, if an `IWriter` interface requires `write` and `flush` methods, then a module that defines top-level `write` and `flush` functions (and calls `zope.interface.moduleProvides(IWriter)`) provides that interface, even though modules in general do not.

This is also the reason that Zope interface methods do not name `self` as a parameter - `self` is an implementation detail particular to class instance methods.

This ability for individual objects to provide an interface becomes particularly useful with objects that wrap another object and dynamically map its methods.

For example, say we have:

```
class IWriter(zope.interface.Interface):
    def write(s):
        """Write stuff"""
    def flush():
        """Flush stuff"""

class TextWriter:
    zope.interface.implements(IWriter)
    def write(self, s):
        ...
    def flush(self):
        ...

tw = TextWriter()

do_something(tw)
```

If we see a problem where `tw` output is not being flushed sometimes, we could instrument the TextWriter methods to display debug info (e.g. `log(timestamp, caller, methodname)`).  However, the code to generate the `timestamp` and `caller` info is complex, and needs to be added in multiple places. And now every `TextWriter` instance will display the debug info.

Instead, we could wrap the particular `TextWriter` of interest in a wrapper object that logs its method calls.

```
class DebugWrapper:

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        ... # generate timestamp and caller
        log(timestamp, caller, name)
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)

dtw = DebugWrapper(tw)

do_something(dtw)
```

Note that `DebugWrapper` is generic. It can wrap any object. It could be imported from a separate library.  It's independent of the `IWriter` interface, and that is good since we can more easily re-use it elsewhere.

But if the `do_something` function expects to receive a provider of the interface `IWriter` we now have the problem that `dtw` satisfies the interface syntax but does not "officially" provide the interface.

This is an important distinction.

Interfaces do not just define a syntactic signature. They also define the semantic meaning of the syntax. With interfaces we can specify whether two objects that provide the same methods actually provide the same semantics. This is a big difference to Python's common use of duck typing, where the same syntax implies the same semantics.

Anyway, the solution to our problem is to inform everyone that the object `dtw` does indeed provide the `IWriter` interface, even though its class `DebugWrapper` does not.

```
zope.interface.directlyProvides(dtw, IWriter)
```